# Double For Loop to calculate averages and store them in matrix

Tags: r, for-loop, mean

I'm having trouble running this double for loop to properly store the calculated values into the matrix (mentioned below). The reason why I elected to use the double For Loop and not apply() or mean() is that I want to obtain the unique combinations of the two columns and eliminate redundancy (explained below). See below for an example:

```
A<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
B<-c(2,3,4,5,6)
Q1<-data.frame(cbind(A,B))
mean<-matrix(nrow=5, ncol = 5)
for(i in 1: length(Q1$A)){
  for(j in 2: length(Q1$B)){
    mean[i,j]<-sum(Q1$A[i]+Q1$B[j])/2
  }
}
```

Here, I attempted to run the entire A vector through the entire B vector while eliminating redundancy, such that A[1] has four values from B[2], and A[2] has three values from B[3]. However, this was my result.

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   NA  2.0  2.5  3.0  3.5
[2,]   NA  2.5  3.0  3.5  4.0
[3,]   NA  3.0  3.5  4.0  4.5
[4,]   NA  3.5  4.0  4.5  5.0
[5,]   NA  4.0  4.5  5.0  5.5
```

While the first column was what I expected, I have values I didn't want. What I want instead is the below matrix output:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   NA  2.0  2.5  3.0  3.5
[2,]   NA   NA  3.0  3.5  4.0
[3,]   NA   NA   NA  4.0  4.5
[4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA  5.0
[5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you interested only in half of the matrix? For example, in the case of `colA <- 1:3` and `colB <- 13:11`, the output matrix becomes asymmetric (e.g. `A[1] + B[3] != A[3] + B[1]`) and you would lose information by looking only at a half of the matrix.

Comment: @MaratTalipov I'm interested in half because I want to grab these values and put them into a column so I can compare it with others in a ggplot. If there's redundancy, then it'll reflect the outcome of the graph.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**[Original Solution (see Update 2 for the faster solutions)]**

```
f.m <- function(Q1) {
    z <- matrix(nrow=nrow(Q1),ncol=nrow(Q1))
    b <- row(z) < col(z)
    z[b] <- (Q1$A[col(z)[b]] + Q1$B[row(z)[b]])/2
    z
}
```

**[Sample output]**

```
f.m(Q1)
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]   NA    2  2.5  3.0  3.5
# [2,]   NA   NA  3.0  3.5  4.0
# [3,]   NA   NA   NA  4.0  4.5
# [4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA  5.0
# [5,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

**[Benchmarking Setup]**

```
f0 <- function(Q1) {
    mean<-matrix(nrow=nrow(Q1), ncol = nrow(Q1))
    for(i in 1: length(Q1$A)){
        for(j in 2: length(Q1$B)){
            mean[i,j]<-sum(Q1$A[i]+Q1$B[j])/2
        }
    }
    mean
}

f1 <- function(Q1) {
    mean<-matrix(nrow=nrow(Q1), ncol = nrow(Q1))
    for(i in 2: length(Q1$A)){
        for(j in i: length(Q1$B)){
            mean[i,j]<-sum(Q1$A[i]+Q1$B[j])/2
        }
    }
    mean
} 

# Note that f0() and f1() don't return the desired result for the sample output

f2 <- function(Q1) {
    mean<-outer(1: length(Q1$A), 
                1: length(Q1$B),
                Vectorize(function(i,j){
                    if(i >= j)
                        return(NA)
                    else 
                        return(sum(Q1$A[i]+Q1$B[j])/2)
                }))
    mean
}

library(rbenchmark)
```

**[Benchmarking Result]**

```
A <- B <- 1:100
Q1<-data.frame(A,B)

benchmark(f0(Q1), f1(Q1), f2(Q1), f.m(Q1), replications = 10)
     test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
4 f.m(Q1)           10   0.011    1.000     0.012    0.000          0         0
1  f0(Q1)           10   3.018  274.364     3.007    0.008          0         0
2  f1(Q1)           10   1.477  134.273     1.474    0.003          0         0
3  f2(Q1)           10   1.777  161.545     1.774    0.002          0         0
```

**[Update 1]**

Another order of running time could be saved by direct calculation of the entire matrix, which avoids messing with costly (comparing to summation) subsetting:

```
f.m2 <- function(Q1) outer(Q1$A,Q1$B,'+')*0.5
```

Another portion of benchmarking:

```
A <- B <- 1:1000
Q1<-data.frame(A,B)
#benchmark(f0(Q1), f1(Q1), f2(Q1), f.m(Q1), replications = 10)
benchmark(f.m(Q1), f.m2(Q1), replications = 10)

      test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
1  f.m(Q1)           10   1.839   10.274     1.746    0.093          0         0
2 f.m2(Q1)           10   0.179    1.000     0.144    0.035          0         0
```

**[Update 2]**

1) As noted by David Arenburg, function `f.m2()` does not produce exactly the expected output, because lower left triangle and main diagonal of the output should be filled with NAs. The function `f.m2()` can be fixed to produce the proper answer at the cost of performance (see benchmarking below).

```
# Suggested by David Arenburg
f.m2.1 <- function(Q1) { 
   Res <- outer(Q1$A,Q1$B,'+')*0.5; 
   Res[lower.tri(Res, diag = TRUE)] <- NA; 
   Res 
}
```

2) Here is another approach suggested by David Arenburg, which makes use of the `CJ` function from the `data.table` package:

```
library(data.table)
f.DA <- function(Q1){ 
  Res <- matrix(rowMeans(CJ(Q1$A, Q1$B)), ncol = nrow(Q1))
  Res[lower.tri(Res, diag = TRUE)] <- NA
  Res 
}
```

3) Here is an `Rcpp`-based approach:

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('NumericMatrix fC(NumericVector A, NumericVector B) {

  int n = A.size();
  NumericMatrix out(n,n);
  std::fill( out.begin(), out.end(), NumericVector::get_na() ) ;

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (int j = i+1; j < n; j++) {
      out(i,j) = 0.5*(A[i] + B[j]);
    }
  }
  return out;
}')
```

4) And another benchmarking study:

```
A <- B <- 1:3000
Q1<-data.frame(A,B)
benchmark(f.m2(Q1), f.m2.1(Q1), f.DA(Q1), fC(Q1$A, Q1$B), replications = 10)

            test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
3       f.DA(Q1)           10   7.442   11.556     6.200    1.209          0         0
2     f.m2.1(Q1)           10   5.111    7.936     4.404    0.661          0         0
1       f.m2(Q1)           10   1.007    1.564     0.733    0.263          0         0
4 fC(Q1$A, Q1$B)           10   0.644    1.000     0.525    0.116          0         0
```

Comment: Actually `f.m2` returns the whole matrix and thus no the desired result. You should probably modify it to `f.m2 <- function(Q1) {
  Res <- outer(Q1$A,Q1$B,'+')*0.5;
  Res[lower.tri(Res,  diag = TRUE)] <- NA;
  Res
}` in order to fill the requirements, it still will be faster than `f.m` though

Comment: You could also add `library(data.table);
f.DA <- function(Q1){
  Res <- matrix(rowMeans(CJ(Q1$A, Q1$B)), ncol = nrow(Q1));
  Res[lower.tri(Res,  diag = TRUE)] <- NA;
  Res
}` which will also beat `f.m` but probably will still slower than `f.m2`

Comment: Thanks @DavidArenburg, I've added your suggestions as well as `Rcpp`-based solution

Answer (score 2):

The second for loop should be:

```
 for(j in (i+1):length(Q1$B))
```

Answer (score 2):

you want to use the `next` keyword to skip the operations you don't need, as in:

```
A<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
B<-c(2,3,4,5,6)
Q1<-data.frame(cbind(A,B))
mean<-matrix(nrow=5, ncol = 5)
for(i in 1: length(Q1$A))
for(j in 2: length(Q1$B)){
    if(i >= j)
        next
    mean[i,j]<-sum(Q1$A[i]+Q1$B[j])/2
}
```

or you could make the iterand of the inner `for` loop conditional on the value of the outer index, as in:

```
mean<-matrix(nrow=5, ncol = 5)
for(i in 2: length(Q1$A)){
    for(j in i: length(Q1$B)){
        mean[i,j]<-sum(Q1$A[i]+Q1$B[j])/2
    }
}
```

or you could use `outer()` as in:

```
mean<-outer(1: length(Q1$A), 
            1: length(Q1$B),
            Vectorize(function(i,j){
                if(i >= j)
                    return(NA)
                else 
                    return(sum(Q1$A[i]+Q1$B[j])/2)
            }))
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly a double For Loop, but you could just use the `outer` function to calculate the averages.

```
outer(Q1$Col1, Q1$Col2, "+")/2
```